# Search query using like function

Tags: mysql

ll've looked into the like function, as well as other solutions but I think what I'm trying to do can be accomplished with one query. Here is what I have so far.

```
"SELECT name FROM tblname where name like '%jons%'"
```

i excepted answer fetch the name "jon" how can i do. please help me

Comment: Why would it fetch `'jon'` when you are searching for names that contain `'jons'`?

Comment: Do you want to match where the name is exactly `jon`? Or Beginning with `jon`, or anywhere it says `jon` in `name`?

Comment: I needed Singular and plural word should come.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `name`
FROM `tblname`
WHERE 'jons' LIKE CONCAT('%', `name`, '%');
```

Also you can use two LIKE methods with `OR` operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name
FROM tblname
WHERE name like 'jon%';
```